# Python pptx - pass html formatted text to paragraph in powerpoint

Tags: python, python-pptx

I have string with html tags and I would like to pass formatting to power point.
The only idea I have now is to split it using some xml library and add bunch of ifs adding formatting to run depending on a tag.

Did you encounter similar problem or have better idea how to approach it?

Comment: please add your attempt for solving the problem (simple working code example)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a method of doing this. For a start, some HTML elements and attributes aren't likely to translate.

I've done a very limited amount of this - and actually it was mostly Markdown I was translating. (The HTML relevance is that I did work with entity references and also `<br/>`.)

I'm sorry to say my code is useless to you.

My advice would be to support a small subset of HTML. Perhaps `<span>` with some limited styling and things like `<br/>`.